# find same values of id and make addition of given json array

Tags: json

My json array is like this :

```
0: {owner_id: 112, date: "2021-08-09T00:00:00", hours_planned: 8, days_since: 0, hours_to_schedule: 0}
1: {owner_id: 56, date: "2021-08-10T00:00:00", hours_planned: 3, days_since: 1, hours_to_schedule: 5}
2: {owner_id: 58, date: "2021-08-10T00:00:00", hours_planned: 8, days_since: 1, hours_to_schedule: 0}
3: {owner_id: 112, date: "2021-08-12T00:00:00", hours_planned: 8, days_since: 3, hours_to_schedule: 0}
4: {owner_id: 57, date: "2021-08-09T00:00:00", hours_planned: 8, days_since: 0, hours_to_schedule: 0}
5: {owner_id: 112, date: "2021-08-10T00:00:00", hours_planned: 8, days_since: 1, hours_to_schedule: 0}
6: {owner_id: 56, date: "2021-08-11T00:00:00", hours_planned: 2, days_since: 2, hours_to_schedule: 6}
7: {owner_id: 56, date: "2021-08-12T00:00:00", hours_planned: 2, days_since: 3, hours_to_schedule: 6}
8: {owner_id: 112, date: "2021-08-11T00:00:00", hours_planned: 8, days_since: 2, hours_to_schedule: 0}
9: {owner_id: 56, date: "2021-08-09T00:00:00", hours_planned: 8, days_since: 0, hours_to_schedule: 0}
```

Now I want to addition of total **hours_planned** of same **owner_id**

I want result like this:-

```
1: {owner_id: 56, date: "2021-08-10T00:00:00", hours_planned: 3, days_since: 1, hours_to_schedule: 5}
6: {owner_id: 56, date: "2021-08-11T00:00:00", hours_planned: 2, days_since: 2, hours_to_schedule: 6}
7: {owner_id: 56, date: "2021-08-12T00:00:00", hours_planned: 2, days_since: 3, hours_to_schedule: 6}
9: {owner_id: 56, date: "2021-08-09T00:00:00", hours_planned: 8, days_since: 0, hours_to_schedule: 0}
```

**owner_id**: 56 Total **hours_planned** = 15

```
0: {owner_id: 112, date: "2021-08-09T00:00:00", hours_planned: 8, days_since: 0, hours_to_schedule: 0}
3: {owner_id: 112, date: "2021-08-12T00:00:00", hours_planned: 8, days_since: 3, hours_to_schedule: 0}
5: {owner_id: 112, date: "2021-08-10T00:00:00", hours_planned: 8, days_since: 1, hours_to_schedule: 0}
8: {owner_id: 112, date: "2021-08-11T00:00:00", hours_planned: 8, days_since: 2, hours_to_schedule: 0}
```

**owner_id**: 112 Total **hours_planned** = 32

```
4: {owner_id: 57, date: "2021-08-09T00:00:00", hours_planned: 8, days_since: 0, hours_to_schedule: 0}
```

**owner_id**: 57 Total **hours_planned** = 8

```
2: {owner_id: 58, date: "2021-08-10T00:00:00", hours_planned: 8, days_since: 1, hours_to_schedule: 0}
```

**owner_id**: 58 Total **hours_planned** = 8

Anyone knows how to do it? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Array.reduce()` to group your values by `owner_id`, this will create an object keyed on this id.

Using `Object.values` will then return the desired array:

```js
const arr = [
    {owner_id: 112, date: "2021-08-09T00:00:00", hours_planned: 8, days_since: 0, hours_to_schedule: 0},
    {owner_id: 56, date: "2021-08-10T00:00:00", hours_planned: 3, days_since: 1, hours_to_schedule: 5},
    {owner_id: 58, date: "2021-08-10T00:00:00", hours_planned: 8, days_since: 1, hours_to_schedule: 0},
    {owner_id: 112, date: "2021-08-12T00:00:00", hours_planned: 8, days_since: 3, hours_to_schedule: 0},
    {owner_id: 57, date: "2021-08-09T00:00:00", hours_planned: 8, days_since: 0, hours_to_schedule: 0},
    {owner_id: 112, date: "2021-08-10T00:00:00", hours_planned: 8, days_since: 1, hours_to_schedule: 0},
    {owner_id: 56, date: "2021-08-11T00:00:00", hours_planned: 2, days_since: 2, hours_to_schedule: 6},
    {owner_id: 56, date: "2021-08-12T00:00:00", hours_planned: 2, days_since: 3, hours_to_schedule: 6},
    {owner_id: 112, date: "2021-08-11T00:00:00", hours_planned: 8, days_since: 2, hours_to_schedule: 0},
    {owner_id: 56, date: "2021-08-09T00:00:00", hours_planned: 8, days_since: 0, hours_to_schedule: 0}
];


const totals = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, cur) => { 
    acc[cur.owner_id] = acc[cur.owner_id] || { owner_id: cur.owner_id, total_hours_planned: 0};
    acc[cur.owner_id].total_hours_planned += cur.hours_planned;
    return acc;
}, {}))

console.log('Totals:', totals)
```